# cannot get context, AT THE FIRST ACTIVITY

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm just trying to build the simplest activity with a Progress dialog, 
but never mind what i do i cannot get the context.
what am i doing wrong ?

here is my code>

```
package projections.tairy.michal.jsontutorial1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog myFirstPrograsDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myFirstPrograsDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "dialog title",
            "dialog message", true);
}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(id, item);
}


}
```

for Some Reason it highlights me MainActivity.this as an Error, and writes wrong 1st argument type, and everywhere I look on-line it says I must be using a fragment, but as you can see I'm clearly doing this in an activity,

can you help me ? what's wrong with my code there ?

*i already tried invalidate and restart, and building my code, both DIDN'T help.

Comment: What version of support library are you using, is everything up to date? I suggest you to make use of AppCompatActivity rather than ActionBarActivity. What IDE are you using? By the way the code shouldn't show a compile error...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myFirstPrograsDialog  = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
myFirstPrograsDialog.setTitle("dialog title");
myFirstPrograsDialog.setMessage("dialog message");
myFirstPrograsDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
myFirstPrograsDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked online, it is a known bug with the latest SDK.
Fixed it By Downgrading my SDK build at the Project Settings.